# How to render icons with crisp edges in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, logo, icon, front-end-development

This is mainly a question about the quality of logos/icons used in Websites. I create **logos/icons** using Illustrator but when I see icons on professional websites (see image and links), they look crisp like a text, with no blurriness. The edges are very clear. For example, please see this image, especially the search icon and the menu list icon:

[image]

1. This is my own [Blog](http://vkcreativework.blogspot.in/p/home.html) that has bad icons, the **Logo** and the **Menu icon**. Both of them are **PNG** images.
2. This is [Entrepreneur](https://www.entrepreneur.com/magazine) website with awesome **menu icon** and **search** icon. If you check the **Inspect Element for mobile** site, you'll see that the search icon and menu icon are not images (I don't know actually the reality). It is using a **pseudo** element. How does it work? Maybe this has something to do with quality.
3. Same is true with [TimeofIndia](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/) website. Here the menu icon is made using **hr** tag, so it's obviously great, but still the **search icon** is beyond understanding as it is using a **pseudo** element.
4. And another scenario is related to this [Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.in/) website's technique. I've seen it at most of the websites, especially Facebook like sites. They use a single image for all icons. How's it possible? If you don't understand please visit this website and check the **URL** of the menu and search icon's image. How's it done?

So first I would like to know how these things work? How these icons render?

Secondly why I'm not getting the quality like them? Should I stop using images like them? I'm asking this because I've tried exporting in many ways using Illustrator, with same dimensions as required, but still quality sucks. If you can see, in my own blog's ([Blog](http://vkcreativework.blogspot.in/p/home.html)) mobile site, the middle horizontal bar is blurred despite the original image looks awesome before upload. Why is that?

I think these are too many questions. I would appreciate if you can provide suitable links to understand these things fully, if explaining them here is not easy.

Thank you.

Comment: Can I improve this question to remove 1 downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use icon fonts for atleast the hamburger menu
2. Since im not in India i get redirected to non-indian site so hard to say.
3. it is a icon font it is defined thus:

   ```
   .s::before {
       color: #fff;
       content: "";
       font: bold 25px/1 "Genericons";
       position: relative;
   }
   ```

   To work it depends on the font `Genericons`
4. They are cropped by css instructions read more here: [css-sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: 3. They have used '\f400' as content. What does it mean?

Comment: Also, I tried to find on Google about Icon fonts but I couldn't find satisfactory results, especially this pseudo element technique. Do you know any site for this?

Comment: @VikasKumar '\f400'  is just the name of the character in the font just like 'a' or 'b' it just has no symbol associated with it in most fonts. The range \e000-\f8ff is one of three so called [private use areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas), meaning theres no formal definition of what that character is representing but the maker of the font can define whatever they want. Examples of its use can be found for example in [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/) that contains lots of standard web icons as font entries in the private use area.

Comment: @VikasKumar and here is the list of font avesomes characters and what location they hold: http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Comment: I tried to print some of the symbols but they didn't render. I tried to put content as '\f400' and '&#xf042;' but both didn't work.

Comment: @VikasKumar But it *only* works if you have that particular font loaded in your browser and associated with the text in question! It has no meaning on any other font.

Comment: Oh yes I just read about this on Stackoverflow. But now what I don't understand is the difference between \wxyz and &#xf042; Are these different formats to represent a symbol? Secondly can I use the latter as content '.......'; ?

Comment: @VikasKumar yes same thing alternate encodin. Yes you can use it in text.

Comment: Ok I'll try soon and will tell you if it works :)

Comment: Well \wxyz format is working and the &#xf042 is not working. I downloaded fonts from here: http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.6.3.zip I tried to use the second format but it didn't render. I copied it from here: http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45860/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-joojaa).

Answer (score 4):

These sites are using vectors. When you export as png you can maintain a lot of quality, but with an svg (vector) you maintain the full integrity of the graphic.

From AI, you can export to svg directly. If you intend to include text in the graphic, you need to "expand" the text to capture the outlines of the letters.

Comment: What about those pseudo concepts and that single image for all icons? Could you please add this to your answer?

Comment: Are you sure all of them are using Vectors for search icons? Did you read the answer below?

Comment: The comments about the font icons are correct. This pseudo element you are asking about is just part of how they load. As for the single image for all icons, this is achieved with [sprite sheets](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

Comment: If you have knowledge about Front end technologies, could you please look at this problem? It's related to SVG. Something is not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678361/why-isnt-svg-and-text-rendering-on-mobile-browsers?noredirect=1#comment66657693_39678361

Comment: Ah, looks like you got an answer. Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: Yep I got the answer. But I have more to ask. What about browsers that don't support SVG. What should do? Use PNG images for them?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know any that don't support them, but PNG is next best option

Comment: So how can I do that? Any hint? We want to replace the SVG when it is not supported.

Comment: How to load PNG? Or how to fall back to PNG?

Comment: How to fall back to PNG.

Comment: [Here](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-svg-fallbacks/) is a link with details.